# Who named the Millennium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, millennium-falcon

[image: Millenium Falcon]
At what point along its journey did a particular YT-1300 freighter become known as the *Millenium Falcon*?  Was it named by Han or Lando, or someone else?  Wookieepedia offers no help other than "at some point."

Comment: Heh. I thought that those were Legos for a minute.

Comment: Possibly content of the upcoming second spin-off about Han.

Comment: @Gallifreian Thanks for finding that other question.  The title doesn't seem like it, but inside it has all the information I was looking for.

Comment: Yeah, that question doesn't have the `millennium-falcon` tag.